# Transfer App to company with renewable subscriptions but subscriptions not working anymore

Tags: app-store-connect, subscriptions

We did transfer an app with auto renewable subs to our account (now allowed since June 2017). We followed instructions from here http://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deved688524f and got the App shared secret from the previous owner. However, new users can't purchase subscriptions anymore. For info, bundle IDs of the IAP are still under the previous owner's name.
 
Anyone went throught the same process?
 
I can't get anyone from Apple on the phone on weekends...

Are we required to create new subscription ids with the new bundle identifier or these are also transferred and working out of the box as previously?

Comment: was this resolved? Can you see anything in logs while querying existing bundle ID's?